# Rotation around a line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Let $F : \mathbb{E}^3 \to \mathbb{E}^3$ be one of the possible orthogonal rotations of angle $5/6 \pi$ around the line $r$ of equations $y-5z + 2 =0$ and $4x-y-10z = 0$.

Determine the matrix associated to $F$ with respect to the canonical basis. Is such a rotation necessarily a direct isometry?

Without explaining the whole solution, what are the main steps of such a problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: What's a "direct isometry"?

Comment: Are you sure that the first equation is correct? If so, this line doesn’t pass through the origin and to represent the rotation as a single matrix you’ll have to pass to homogeneous coordinates and use a $4\times4$ matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break the computation into a few steps.

1. Compute the $3 \times 3$ matrix $M$ associated to the rotation of angle $5/6\pi$ around the $z$-axis.
2. Use the given equations to compute the unit column vector $u_r$ parallel to the line $r$.
3. Compute an orthonormal matrix $R$ which takes the unit column vector $u_z = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ to $u_r$, i.e. $R u_z = u_r$.
4. Compute $RMR^{-1}$.

Comment: The required rotation isn’t a linear transformation of $\mathbb E^3$—the line doesn’t pass through the origin.

Comment: Good point, I did not notice that constant term. So the conjugating transformation will need to be composed with an appropriate translation (and, as your comment to the answer says, it won't be just a $3 \times 3$ matrix transformation).